# R running count based on different column

Tags: r, cumsum

I'd like to get the running count of something in ColumnA based on how many times it has previously appeared in ColumnB. Ideally, this count could also be subset by ColumnC.

For example, I'd like to get a running total of the winner's previous LOSSES or the loser's previous WINS here:

```
#create df
year <- c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016)
winner <- c('sam', 'ryan', 'sally', 'sally', 'ryan', 'sally', 'mike', 'ryan', 'mike', 'sam')
loser <- c('mike', 'mike', 'ryan', 'sam', 'sam', 'mike', 'sally', 'mike', 'ryan', 'sally')
df <- data.frame(year, winner, loser)

#successul methods for getting winner's cumulative wins or loser's cumulative losses
df <- as.data.table(df)[, winner_wins := seq(.N), by = "winner"][]
df <- as.data.table(df)[, loser_losses := seq(.N), by = "loser"][]

#successul methods for getting winner's cumulative wins or loser's cumulative losses by year
df <- df %>% group_by(year, winner) %>% mutate(winner_wins = row_number())
df <- df %>% group_by(year, loser) %>% mutate(loser_losses = row_number())

#failed attempt to get winner's cumulative losses by year
df <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(winner_losses = cumsum(winner == loser & year == year))
```

I'd like the output to be my original data frame but with four new columns: winner_cum_wins, winner_cum_losses, loser_cum_wins, loser_cum_losses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Cumulatively count number of times column value appears in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491258/r-cumulatively-count-number-of-times-column-value-appears-in-other-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a data frame of all you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate(match_id_year = row_number()) %>% 
    gather(outcome, name, -year, -match_id_year) %>% 
    arrange(year, match_id_year) %>% 
    group_by(year, name) %>% 
    mutate(cum_wins_year = cumsum(outcome == "winner"),
           cum_losses_year = cumsum(outcome == "loser"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year <- c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016)
winner <- c('sam', 'ryan', 'sally', 'sally', 'ryan', 'sally', 'mike', 'ryan', 'mike', 'sam')
loser <- c('mike', 'mike', 'ryan', 'sam', 'sam', 'mike', 'sally', 'mike', 'ryan', 'sally')
df <- data.frame(year, winner, loser)

#successul methods for getting winner's cumulative wins or loser's cumulative losses by year
df <- df %>% group_by(year, winner) %>% mutate(winner_wins = row_number())
df <- df %>% group_by(year, loser) %>% mutate(loser_losses = row_number())
```

I have created the following function which counts the previous occurrences of `x` in `y`.

```
count_wins_losses <- function(x,y){
  n = length(x)
  counts = numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    counts2 = numeric(i)
    for (j in 1:i){counts2[j] = sum(x[i] == y[j])}
    counts[i] = sum(counts2)
  }
  return(counts)
}
```

I used `split` to apply the function to each year.

```
# count the cummullative wins of the losers
loser_cum_wins <- df %>%
  split(year) %>%
  lapply(., function(x) count_winner_losses(x$loser, x$winner)) %>%
  unlist()

# count the cummulative losses of the winners
winner_cum_losses <- df %>%
  split(year) %>%
  lapply(., function(x) count_winner_losses(x$winner, x$loser)) %>%
  unlist()
```

The `arrange`ment is done here so that the years in `df` and the `loser_cum_wins` and `winner_cum_losses` match.

```
df <- arrange(df, year)
df$loser_cum_wins <- loser_cum_wins
df$winner_cum_losses <- winner_cum_losses
df

## A tibble: 10 x 7
## Groups:   year, loser [6]
#    year winner loser winner_wins loser_losses loser_cum_wins winner_cum_losses
#   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>       <int>        <int>          <dbl>             <dbl>
# 1 2016. sally  mike            1            1             0.                0.
# 2 2016. mike   sally           1            1             1.                1.
# 3 2016. ryan   mike            1            2             1.                0.
# 4 2016. mike   ryan            2            1             1.                2.
# 5 2016. sam    sally           1            2             1.                0.
# 6 2017. sam    mike            1            1             0.                0.
# 7 2017. ryan   mike            1            2             0.                0.
# 8 2017. sally  ryan            1            1             1.                0.
# 9 2017. sally  sam             2            1             1.                0.
#10 2017. ryan   sam             2            2             1.                1.
```

Another way to use the `count_wins_losses()` function is to filter `df` by `year` and use the function for each split, then combine the results afterwards.

```
df2016 <- df %>%
  filter(year == 2016)
df2017 <- df %>%
  filter(year == 2017)

df2016$loser_cum_wins <- with(df2016, count_winner_losses(loser, winner))
df2016$winner_cum_losses <- with(df2016, count_winner_losses(winner, loser))
df2017$loser_cum_wins <- with(df2017, count_winner_losses(loser, winner))
df2017$winner_cum_losses <- with(df2017, count_winner_losses(winner, loser))
rbind(df2016,df2017)
```

Comment: This seems to simply be what I already had, no? Winner's cumulative wins and loser's cumulative losses? What I'm looking for is winner's cumulative LOSSES and loser's cumulative WINS.

Comment: @Jim, see my modification.

Comment: I have modified, my answer @Jim. But it seems this has a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491258/r-cumulatively-count-number-of-times-column-value-appears-in-other-column?rq=1